# How to read excel sheet data using VB.net or VBA in UiPath

Tags: vba, vb.net, uipath, rpa

How to read excel sheet data using VB.net.
i want to export excel sheet data as Datatable.

If i use read range activity then i am getting read range error. so i want to read excel sheet through vb.net or VBA and i want to return those data as data table.

could not read range error getting while i tries with read range activity and i tried read range workbook activity also. it is also not working.

Comment: Update your question with what you’ve tried so for with a clear description of what and where it’s not working as intended

Answer (score 0):

If you left empty range, activity will get all available range (with data).
If you have spaces in the middle of data (i.e, you have 10 rows, then 2 blanks, and 5 rows more) you should set bigger range that your data (i.e, "A1:Z999").

Read range activity already returns a datatable.

I hope my post helps.
Regards.